# Partition a stable (Middle School Math)

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, tiling

Middle School Math Club Question :
The stable, $6$ yards by $6$ yards with concrete walls, is divided by internal wooden partitions into stalls $1$ yard by $2$ yards.
What could be the total length of the wooden partitions? Find all possible answers.

My daughter had this question at her Math Club. There is no mention of thickness of the wooden partitions. So she is a tad confused on this.

Comment: I think the idea is that the thickness of the partitions doesn't affect their length. In reality it does, slightly, because if you put a partition from the north wall to the south wall then it takes slightly less than 6 yards of material to join that partition to the east wall and to the west wall. But this is a math problem, where you can buy 60 cantaloupes and nobody looks at you like you're crazy. So I would just answer the question as if the partitions had zero thickness.

Answer (score 4):

**"My daughter had this question .... she is a tad confused on this."**

It is not her fault : I too am confused , because that Question is almost meaningless.

(1) When the Stable has concrete walls , how can the horses enter & leave ?
(2) Even if we can assume some gate (where ? what length ?) , then should we tightly pack the Stalls & horses , leaving no corridor or way or room for horses to walk in ?

[[ We generally take Partitions to have **theoretically** Zero thickness , which is **Practically** negligible thickness ]]

**With those caveats , here is a "straight-forward" way to get "some" answer ....**

Area of Stable is $6 \times 6 = 36$
Perimeter of Stable is $6 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 6 \times 4 = 24$

Area of Stall is $1 \times 2 = 2$
Perimeter of Stall is $1 + 2 + 1 + 2 = 2 ( 1 + 2 ) = 6$

Within that Stable Area , we can have $36 / 2 = 18$ Stalls , with no space or aisle or way to enter & leave.

That will require $18 \times 6 = 108$ Wooden Partition length.
We do not require Partition where there is a wall , hence we can exclude that :
$108-24=84$ Partition length

This is Double Counting the Internal Partitions , where-ever two Stalls have Common Partition.
Hence we should take half :
$84/2=42$ Partitions

**Thus $42$ is the Maximum Partition length we will ever require. When we have aisles , corridors or ways to enter , we will have fewer Stalls & we will require lesser Partitions ....**

**A BETTER WAY TO WORD THE QUESTION**

Avoiding all the meaninglessness , we can make the Equivalent Question like this :
We have a $6 \times 6$ Square.
Draw $1 \times 2$ Dominoes inside it.
Maximize the Number of Dominoes.
We want to know the total length of lines involved.

Answer : 42

Comment: **'no corridor or way or room for horses to walk in ?'** Exactly my first thought, too. +1.

Comment: Another way to get the answer: first partition into $1\times1$ squares, which needs $30+30=60$ unit lengths, then remove the middles of the $18$ dominoes, which leaves $42$.

Comment: Nice way , @JaapScherphuis , wording with Dominoes will suggest other ways too , without worrying about horsing around

Comment: @Prem -1 for that bad pun

Answer (score 1):

First divide the total area into nine 2*2 yard squares using two vertical dividers and two horizontal dividers of 6 yards each giving a sub total of 24 yards.

9 square cubicles each require a 2 yard sub-partition = +18 yards.
Orientation of sub partitions does not matter.

Total yardage of wooden partitions = 24+18 = 42 yards.

P.S. Lifts will have to be installed to get the horses in and out.

**Alternatively**, using a method similar to the one suggested by JAAP in the comments:

First divide the total area into 36 squares of 1 yard by 1 yard using 5 vertical and 5 horizontal dividers of 6 yards each adding up to 5 * 2 * 6 = 60 yards.

Now remove 18 sections of 1 yard each and the total required yardage is 60-18 = 42 yards. This covers all possible permutations of dividing the stalls up.

Comment: Looks ok , may be a little better with MathJAX. The horse PUN was because horses are generally involved with Pun-ters.

Comment: No Issues [ other than MathJAX ] & Nice alternatives +1 !